# Function or signal as machine learning model output

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am new to machine learning. I've seen that machine learning models such as ANN or SVM can be used to predict scalar outputs taking scalar inputs.

I am trying to create a model that has a number of scalar inputs and outputs a function (the 'output signal' from now on), instead of scalar outputs. What model should I use for this? The output signal is a monotonically decreasing function, with its image ranging from 0 to 1 (always starting at 1 and settling at 0), and its domain from 0 up to a certain time when it settles to zero.

I thought perhaps I could either 'discretize' the output signal and take the discrete points as different scalar outputs. For example, take its value $y_n$ at different times $t_n$, and setting $y_n$ as the outputs of the model.

Another way I thought that could perhaps work is applying a Fourier transform and do the same with the coefficients.

Is there a better way to do this? I will also have little amount of signals (200-400) to train my model, and I can add scalar inputs as needed.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Thank you very much D.W. for your reply. I'm sorry for cross-posting, I deleted the other question. I added additional information to the original question.

Comment: You describe plausible approaches.  "Better" is a matter of opinion and hard to judge without knowing lots of intricate details of your particular method.  It may be challenging to ensure that the output function is monotonically decreasing.

Comment: Also, *what* are you trying to learn? Is it a **specific** unkown decreasing function? How do you represent the input? What does it correspond to?

Comment: Thank you D.W. and nir shahar for your replies. I very much appreciate them. 

D.W.: I understand you are referring that it may be challenging to make the model output a monotonically decreasing function, correct? The output signal is somewhat like a cummulative distribution function. Perhaps if I take the derivative of it I would solve this issue? 

In any case, I understand you think both "solutions" I propose would be reasonable?

Comment: nir shahar: I will give you a bit more details. What I'm trying to do is predict a physical signal with some molecular descriptors (a vector of scalar inputs). I can do experiments with different molecules, which each have their molecular descriptors, and find this output signal. I want to predict the signal for a hypothetical molecule. This is known in cheminformatics as quantitative structure-property relation, although normally the output is a scalar too, such as the viscosity. In my case, the output is a signal as described above. Thank you!

Comment: That seems like an excellent idea: have the neural network output/predict the derivative of the output signal (you can easily construct a neural net output layer that forces the outputs to be non-negative), then as a post-processing step, compute the cumulative sums.  I like that -- that is simple and clean and might work well.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks again for your valuable insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approaches you mention are plausible.  I will mention two more possibilities.

## Monotonic neural nets

You are imagining building a network $F$ that takes one input, the scalar inputs (call them $s$), and produces an output signal $F(s)$ that is itself a function.

An alternative is to build a network that takes two inputs: (1) your scalar inputs $s$, (2) a time $t$, and outputs the value of the function at time $t$.  In other words, you build a network $F$ that evaluates the output signal at a given value $t$ to yield $F(s,t)$ -- this is the value of the output signal at time $t$.

There are methods in the literature for ensuring that the neural network is a monotonic function of $t$.  See, e.g.,

[Unconstrained Monotonic Neural Networks](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/8433-unconstrained-monotonicneuralnetworks.pdf).  Antoine Wehenkel, Gilles Louppe.  NeurIPS 2019.

[Application of the back propagation neural network
algorithm with monotonicity constraints for two-group classification problems](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1540-5915.1993.tb00462.x?casa_token=9JqVlZOi5Z0AAAAA:ZiHEk8xA1lUTdjqA0MiGhpLyzRrvgMJM7asYkZjDWJbY0l-e8rbpqABMFN-dagW3LpGOy90Hw5Q61Iec1Q).  Norman P. Archer, Shouhong Wang.  Decision Sciences 24(1).

[Counterexample-Guided Learning of Monotonic Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.08852).  Aishwarya Sivaraman, Golnoosh Farnadi, Todd Millstein, Guy Van den Broeck.

The easiest approach is to force all neural network weights to be non-negative (the bias terms can be negative).  This is not the optimal method, but it is easy to implement.  The others are complex enough to implement that they might not be worth it.

In your case, you'd have to adapt these methods so that $F$ is monotonic with respect to $t$ but not necessarily with respect to $s$.  I think you might be able to do that with an architecture something like $F(s,t) = G(H(s),t)$ where $G$ is monotonic and $H$ is not.

## Isotonic regression

Another possibility might be to use your neural network to produce an output signal, as you described, and then use [isotonic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotonic_regression) as a post-processing step to make the output signal monotonic.

A potential showstopper problem with this idea is that I'm not sure whether isotonic regression is differentiable, which is needed for doing end-to-end training of the entire process.

Comment: Thank you D.W. for your valuable response! I didn't think about taking $t_n$ as an input, that's a smart idea. Do you think that it is a better solution than having $n$ outputs? $n$ could be in the order of 100. I will study the resources you have shared regarding monotonic neural nets. I appreciate your reply!

Comment: @JamesCraft, I don't know.  In machine learning it's often hard to tell in advance what will work best; often you have to try multiple approaches and see what works.  If your approaches work well enough then you are good, otherwise maybe this gives some additional ideas you could explore.